# multiple selection is not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is my following code

```
           <select id="SelectEmptyPoints" multiple="multiple">
                 <option>Point 1</option>
                 <option>Point 2</option>
                 <option>Point 3</option>
                 <option>None</option>
             </select>
```

onchange funtion :

```
 function SetEmptyPoints(param) {    
 var length = param.selectedOptions.length;
}
```

this function working except IE... i can't get the selectedOptions(multiple selection) length.. how to resolve..
but this function is working chrome, firefox,.... it's not working only IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery:`$("#SelectEmptyPoints").find("option:selected").length`.It wiil work on ie11.I've tested.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `selectedOptions` property is [not implemented in IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement#Browser_compatibility) yet so you can use a cross platform solution like

```
function SetEmptyPoints(param) {    
    var length = $(param).val().length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will not work on IE 9.0 or its previous versions.
There are some other tags which won't work on IE. Try using Latest IE, the code will work.