# The div wrapped multi select drop down not working in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to build a UI add-remove items component using two multi-select drop downs. [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/archanabr05/bbrn7auv/2/).

```css
div {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background-color: #e4eaec;
}

div select {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: scroll;
  background-color: #fff;
}

div h4 {
  text-align: center;
}

div.section-two-arrows {
  border: none;
  padding-top: 150px;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  .fa {
    font-size: 2.8em;
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="add-remove-items-component">
  <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5 section-one">
    <h4>Available Functions</h4>
    <select id="avail-functions" class="select-box-style" name="availFunc" multiple>
      <option>Value 1</option>
      <option>Value 2</option>
      <option>Value 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 section-two-arrows">
    <span class="fa fa-angle-double-right" title="Add All items from Left to Right"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-angle-right" title="Add selected items from Left to Right"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-angle-left" title="Add All items from Right to Left"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-angle-double-left" title="Add selected items from Right to Left"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5 section-three">
    <h4>Selected Functions</h4>
    <select id="sel-functions" class="select-box-style" name="selFunc" multiple>
      <option>Value 1</option>
      <option>Value 2</option>
      <option>Value 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

This component works well in chrome, but not in IE.

The problem with IE is that the first select box does not work, but the second one works just fine.

If I remove the div wrapped to the select box, it works fine. But I cannot make it responsive and the alignment of the page will be disturbed.

Comment: which version of IE, you've tried? Its looking fine in IE 11

Comment: This answer may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28803589/multiple-selection-is-not-working-in-ie